# Build failed after GoogleMaps.cn1lib update

Tags: codenameone

After an update to `GoogleMaps.cn1lib` build failed, I don't understand if I missing something or there some build issue.

My build params are as follows:

```
android.playService.maps=true
android.GoogleMaps.minPlayServicesVersion=9.4.0
```

You can find the full log [here](https://pastebin.com/Ks7gVLNp).

Can you help me with some hints or related material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the new cn1lib update.